# SymPy dsolve with a parameter gives a wrong answer when the parameter is zero

Tags: python, sympy

#### My Code

I have a program that calculates the solutions to a 2nd-order differential equation, like in the code snippet below:

```
import sympy as sp
print('sympy version:', sp.__version__)

t = sp.symbols('t', real=True, nonnegative=True)
n = sp.symbols('n', integer=True, nonnegative=True)
f = sp.symbols('f', cls=sp.Function)

diff_eq = sp.Eq(f(t).diff(t, 2) + n**2*f(t), 0)

print('general solution:', sp.dsolve(diff_eq, f(t)))
print('solution at n=0 (pre-subs):', sp.dsolve(diff_eq.subs(n, 0), f(t)))
print('solution at n=0 (post-subs):', sp.dsolve(diff_eq, f(t)).subs(n, 0))
```

Results:

> `sympy version: 1.3`
>
> `general solution: Eq(f(t), C1*sin(n*t) + C2*cos(n*t))`
>
> `solution at n=0 (pre-subs): Eq(f(t), C1 + C2*t)`
>
> `solution at n=0 (post-subs): Eq(f(t), C2)`

#### My Problem

The solution form for a general `n` does not seem to accurately describe the specific solution form for `n=0`. Specifically, using `dsolve` first and `subs(n, 0)` second produces different results than using `subs(n, 0)` first and `dsolve` second, even though the two should be logically equivalent.

Can somebody explain the reason for the discrepancy in my results? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be considered a bug in `dsolve` logic: it finds two eigenvalues `n` and `-n` and treats them as different without considering the special case `n=0` when they are equal. Ideally it would output a Piecewise like the following code does.

```
sol_nonzero = sp.dsolve(diff_eq, f(t)).rhs
sol_zero = sp.dsolve(diff_eq.subs(n, 0), f(t)).rhs
sol_complete = sp.Piecewise((sol_nonzero, sp.Ne(n, 0)), (sol_zero, True))
print('general solution:', sol_complete)
print('solution at n=0:', sol_complete.subs(n, 0))
```

This prints

```
general solution: Piecewise((C1*sin(n*t) + C2*cos(n*t), Ne(n, 0)), (C1 + C2*t, True))
solution at n=0: C1 + C2*t
```

A more familiar mathematical form is provided by `sp.pprint(sol_complete)`.

```
⎧C₁⋅sin(n⋅t) + C₂⋅cos(n⋅t)  for n ≠ 0
⎨
⎩        C₁ + C₂⋅t          otherwise
```